# How to randomly reduce euclidean distance between two points?

Tags: algorithms

Let's suppose for example that I have two vectors of size 19 with values between the range of 0 and 1. Now lets suppose the euclidean distance between vectors A and B is 0.5.

How would I develop an algorithm to make A randomly move closer to B (Like a mutation that randomly moves A closer to B). So the euclidean distance between these two points would be smaller than 0.5.

Comment: I just need this to mutate a detector closer to the best detector according to this article "MAIS-IDS: A distributed intrusion detection system using multi-agent AIS approach" they don't provide an algorithm for this and don't explain the mutation process

Comment: Hi. You would like $A$ to be the same as $B$ ? Or only closer such that the euclidean distance less than 0.5? Assuming that currently it is equal to 0.5

Comment: Only closer. But in a random way. A is gonna be closer to B but not the same the position... it will just be a random position closer to B.